# USB 'boot error'; possibly bad files?

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb

So, while updating to the latest version of Ubuntu, the upgrade stopped halfway through and did not fully upgrade.  Due to this, my current version of ubuntu is unusable as i can only use the command line (the GUI will not pop up, wifi does not work, login in infinite loop.).

So, I am trying to reinstall Ubuntu back onto the computer by downloading the .iso from a Mac and then transferring using a USB.  This is bringing up a black screen with 'Boot Error',  and nothing else.

I am using the iso file from http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ and unetbootin for Mac.
Why is the startup not possible with this configuration?

Edit:
      I was looking at the files created by unetbootin and I noticed a program in it called 'setup.exe'.  Is it possible the boot fails because it needs Windows to run the file and I only have Ubuntu on the machine?

Answer (score -2):

Use rufus https://rufus.akeo.ie/ and try installing from there

Comment: Rufus is a Windows program and @John Doe said they're creating the USB stick from a Mac.